# How to plot a graph of a function with undefined constants?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to plot a graph of a function with "undefined" constants. Specifically, I am trying to plot the following function:

`$$\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\pi}}e^{-\lambda(x-a)^2}$$`

The original problem just states that `$\lambda$` and `$a$` are given constants. The code I'm using to plot this is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate,mathtools,amsmath,mathabx,fancyhdr,graphicx,lastpage,pgfplots}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage[margin=.7in]{geometry}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot[red,domain=-10*a:10*a,samples=201,]{sqrt(\lambda/\pi)exp(-\lambda*(x-a)^2)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This doesn't produce anything, however. Any help on how to get this to work?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I've updated with that info. If it's preferred, I can copy and paste my entire code. This is the specific problem I'm having, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the purpose is to get a general idea of the graph of the function for different values of `\lambda` and `a`, so one possibility would be to use a group of plots; in each group you keep one of the parameters constant, and plot the graph for the functions resulting from assigning some fixed different values to the other variable. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2},height=5cm,width=5cm]
\nextgroupplot[title={$a=-1$}]
\foreach \clambda/\mycolor in {0,1,2}
{
  \addplot[blue,domain=0:5,samples=100]{sqrt(\clambda/pi)*exp(-\clambda*((x+1)^2)};
}
\nextgroupplot[title={$a=0$}]
\foreach \clambda in {0,1,2}
{
  \addplot[blue,domain=0:5,samples=100]{sqrt(\clambda/pi)*exp(-\clambda*((x)^2)};
}
\nextgroupplot[title={$a=1$}]
\foreach \clambda in {0,1,2}
{
  \addplot[blue,domain=0:5,samples=100]{sqrt(\clambda/pi)*exp(-\clambda*((x-1)^2)};
}
\nextgroupplot[title={$a=2$}]
\foreach \clambda in {0,1,2}
{
  \addplot[blue,domain=0:5,samples=100]{sqrt(\clambda/pi)*exp(-\clambda*((x-2)^2)};
}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graphs of the function given by $\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\pi}}\exp(-\lambda(x-a)^2)$. Each subfigure shows the graphs for $\lambda\in \{0, 1, 2\}$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]